# pandas operation by group

Tags: python, pandas, date, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [205,205,205, 211, 211, 211]
                  , 'date': pd.to_datetime(['2019-12-01','2020-01-01', '2020-02-01'
                                           ,'2019-12-01' ,'2020-01-01', '2020-03-01'])})
df

    id  date
0   205 2019-12-01
1   205 2020-01-01
2   205 2020-02-01
3   211 2019-12-01
4   211 2020-01-01
5   211 2020-03-01
```

where the column `date` is made by consecutive months for `id 205` but not for `id 211`.

**I want to keep only the observations (`id`) for which I have monthly data without jumps.** In this example I want:

```
    id  date
0   205 2019-12-01
1   205 2020-01-01
2   205 2020-02-01
```

Here I am collecting the `id` to keep:

```
keep_id = []
for num in pd.unique(df.index):
    temp = (df.loc[df['id']==num,'date'].dt.year - df.loc[df['id']==num,'date'].shift(1).dt.year) * 12 + df.loc[df['id']==num,'date'].dt.month - df.loc[df['id']==num,'date'].shift(1).dt.month
    temp.values[0] = 1.0 # here I correct the first entry
    if (temp==1.).all():
        keep_id.append(num)
```

where I am using `(df.loc[num,'date'].dt.year - df.loc[num,'date'].shift(1).dt.year) * 12 + df.loc[num,'date'].dt.month - df.loc[num,'date'].shift(1).dt.month` to compute the difference in months from the previous `date` for every `id`.

This seems to work when tested on a small portion of `df`, but I'm sure there is a better way of doing this, maybe using the `.groupby()` method.

**Since `df` is made of millions of observations my code takes too much time (and I'd like to learn a more efficient and pythonic way of doing this)**

Comment: Strongly recommend you *don't* set your index to the `id` column. If you do that your index no longer has unique values for each row and loses much of its power and utility.

Comment: Ok thank you. I was thinking about it. I'll change it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is use groupby-filter rather than a groupby apply.

```
df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: not (x.date.diff() > pd.Timedelta(days=32)).any())
```

provides exactly:

```
    id       date
0  205 2019-12-01
1  205 2020-01-01
2  205 2020-02-01
```

And indeed, I would keep the index unique, there are too many useful characteristics to retain.

Both this response and Michael's above are correct in terms of output. In terms of performance, they are very similar as well:

```
%timeit df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: not (x.date.diff() > pd.Timedelta(days=32)).any())
1.48 ms ± 12.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

and

```
%timeit df[df.groupby('id')['date'].transform(lambda x: x.diff().max() < pd.Timedelta(days=32))]
1.7 ms ± 163 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

For most operations, this difference is negligible.

Comment: Could you please add where `dt` is from? And yes, I did a `.reset_index()` to have it unique

Comment: Apologies, edited response, I had used the datetime timedelta, but the pandas one would work equally fine.

Comment: With larger dataframes your approach is significantly faster. I tried with `df = pd.concat([df] * 10**5)`. Your solution `10 loops, best of 3: 57.2 ms per loop`, my solution `10 loops, best of 3: 131 ms per loop`.  I didn't knew about [`groupby.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) before.

Comment: Didn't expect that big of a difference, thanks for checking.

Comment: Great! This took me 30 minutes, can't imagine my original code

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach. Only ~3x faster in my tests.

```
df[df.groupby('id')['date'].transform(lambda x: x.diff().max() < pd.Timedelta(days=32))]
```

Out:

```
          date
id            
205 2019-12-01
205 2020-01-01
205 2020-02-01
```